# How to show login page outside the layout using vue js 3?

Tags: vuejs3

I want to show login page outside the layout but unfortuntly i see the sidebar and header on login page sidebar and header should not be on login page  please help me how can i resolve that thank u ?

[image: Login page]

**App.vue**

```
  <script setup>
    import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
    import Layout from './components/Layouts/Layout.vue'
    </script>
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <Layout></Layout>
      </div>
        <RouterView />
    </template>
    
    <script>
    
    export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
        Layout,
      
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**router\index.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/DashBoard.vue')
    },
  
  ]
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional rendering to hide/show elements based on the current route

```html
<Layout v-if="route.path !== '/'"></Layout>
```

```js
<script setup>
    import { RouterLink, RouterView, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
    import Layout from './components/Layouts/Layout.vue'

    const route = useRoute();
</script>
```

Also, not sure why you have two script tags.  You don't need to register components with the Composition API (script setup), so you can/should remove the second script